# OpenLayers: Wrap data around the globe

Tags: openlayers-2, globe

With my current implementation if I create a point it is visible only on the first map view. If I move around e.g. move to the right the new view without point is shown. Is there any posibility to add point around the globe?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I fixed this with setting `wrapX` to `true` in `VectorSource`.